# Node App.Js Error

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

Enter code here I am having an error starting node `app.js` im the cmd prompt as `administrator`.

I have a windows operating system and have tried uninstalling the node modules and installing npm again.

Thank you in advance

**I receive:**

```
C:\Users\dnort>run app.js
'run' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\dnort>npm init
This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sensible defaults.

See `npm help json` for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use `npm install <pkg>` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.
package name: (dnort)
version: (1.0.0)
description:
git repository:
keywords:
author:
license: (ISC)
About to write to C:\Users\dnort\package.json:

{
  "name": "dnort",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "botkit-middleware-watson": "^1.6.1",
    "botkit-sms": "^1.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "description": ""
}


Is this ok? (yes)

C:\Users\dnort>node app.js
module.js:538
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\dnort\app.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Comment: Can you make sure if the file `C:\Users\dnort\app.js` exists?

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I changed the directory all together to...

C:\Users\dnort\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\

I double checked in the folder above the app.js doesn't exist period. How do I create this?

Comment: app.js would be any program you write that you execute using Node.js. Simply open a text editor and write your code. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Problem solved thanks mate. Using IBM Watson Conversation to make a sms chatbot with Twilio integration